# Print a square of asterisks out from user input?

Tags: c

I'm very beginner in C programming, and I'm having some issues with making a square of asterisks based on user input, so if the user enters 5 as the input, then it should produce a 5x5 square. I keep getting a single line of asterisks; what am I doing wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h> 

int main(void)
{ 
    int size; 
    int i; 
    int j;

    printf(" Please enter the size of the square"); 
    scanf("%d", &size); 

    for( i=0; i< size;i++); 
    {
        for( j=0; j< size; j++)
        {
             printf("*");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with your first for loop. remove the semicolon that you have kept after declaring for loop.

If you keep semicolon then the for loop well be terminated.

```
for( i=0; i< size;i++);
```

Answer (score 1):

> for( i=0; i< size;i++);

Try to remove semicolon

Answer (score 0):

On this line:

```
for( i=0; i< size;i++);
```

Get rid of the semicolon and it will work.

You don't need semicolons on lines that start blocks of code, only on individual statements.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the last `;` from the line

```
for( i=0; i< size;i++);
```

It needs to be

```
for( i=0; i< size;i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code: It should help:
I only removed a semicolon at the end of the first loop because, if a semi-colon is available, the loop terminates there and does not proceed further.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
int main(void)
{ 
    int size; 
    int i; 
    int j;
    printf(" Please enter the size of the square"); 
    scanf("%d", &size); 

    for( i=0; i< size;i++)
    { 
        for( j=0; j< size; j++)
        { 
           printf("*");  
        }
        printf("\n"); 
    } 
    return 0; 
}
```